# Form validation not working when using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm currently using ajax to auto-save a form. Codeigniter's form validation function doesn't seems to be working when using ajax. Anyone knows whats the problem here?

PHP:

```
function autoSavePublicationDetails()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_author', 'First author', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $data['message'] = validation_errors();
    }
    else
    {
        $newRow = json_decode($_POST['json']);
        $claim_id = $_POST['claim_id'];
        //$this->publicationClaim_model->updateClaim($newRow,$claim_id);
        //$data['claim_id'] = $claim_id;
        $data['message'] = "Success";
    }

    print json_encode($data);
}
```

Jquery:

```
setInterval(function(){
        var date = new Date();
        var dateFormat = date.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + date.getMonth()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + " " + ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

        var claimObj = {
            first_author            : $('#first_author').val(),
            authors                 : $('#authors').val(),
            publication_title       : $('#publication_title').val(),
            source                  : $('#source').val(),
            publication_submitted   : $('#publication_submitted :selected').val(),
            research_bank_number    : $('#research_bank_number').val(),
            research_code_1         : $('#research_code_1 :selected').val(),
            research_code_2         : $('#research_code_2 :selected').val(),
            research_code_3         : $('#research_code_3 :selected').val(),
            issn                    : $('#issn').val(),
            type_of_publication     : $('#type_of_publication :selected').val(),
            claim_type              : $('input[name="claim_type"]').val(),
            claim_author            : $('input[name="claim_author"]').val(),
            claim_date              : dateFormat,
            user_id                 : $('input[name="user_id"]').val()
        };

        var json_data = JSON.stringify(claimObj);
        var className;


        $.post("autoSavePublicationDetails",
            {
                '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>':'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>',
                'json'      : json_data,
                'claim_id'  : $('#claim_id').val()
            },
            function(data,status){
                console.log("Status: " + status);
                var jsonReturn = $.parseJSON(data);
                alert(jsonReturn.message);

                if (jsonReturn.message == "Success")
                {
                    className = 'label label-success';
                    $('#message').addClass(className);
                    $('#message').text('Data saved.');
                }
                else
                {
                    className = 'label label-danger';
                    $('#message').addClass(className);
                    $('#message').text('Form not saved.');
                }

                $('#message').fadeIn();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#message').fadeOut();
                    $('message').removeClass()
                }, 1000);
            });
    }, 10000);
```

I tried alerting the validation errors. It says that my first_author field is empty even when I already entered the some text inside.

Json that is passed to controller:

[image]

Comment: @Nikolay may have a point. Does your handler page expect method= POST or method = GET?

Comment: I'm getting the json_data from POST i think, `$claim_id = $_POST['claim_id'];` if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `$.post()` try to use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)